# NullpointerException desde una Clase (Fragmento) a la hora de llamar un método en otra Clase

Tags: android, fragment, nullpointerexception

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Android que consta de una clase `MainActivity`, una clase llamada `DatabaseManager` y otra clase llamada `Fragmento1`

Estoy trabajando con un `Tabhost` de 3 pestañas, cada pestaña es representada por una clase(`Fragmento1, Fragmento2, Fragmento3`)

la clase `Fragmento1` infla el layout xml del tab 1 y asi sucesivamente.

Desde el fragmento 1 deseo realizar la inserción de un registro a una base de datos, la inserción la realizo mediante un método que se encuentra en la clase Fragmento1 llamada `guardarUsuario();` este método recoge todos los datos para luego enviarlos por parámetros a un método llamado `insertar();` de la clase `DataBaseManager`

pero a la hora de llamar al método me indica `NullPointer Exception`, **¿Qué puede estar pasando?**

```
public class Fragmento1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private DataBase manager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        Resources res = getResources();
        Context context = getContext();


        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spGender);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                R.array.genders, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);




        Button btnGuardar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(this);




        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnGuardar:
                guardarUsuario();

                break;

        }
    }

    public void guardarUsuario() {


        String nombre, apellido, sexo;
        int edad=0, estatura=0;

        EditText nombreId = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.campoNombre);
        EditText apellidoId = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.campoApellido);
        EditText edadId = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.campoEdad);
        Spinner sexoId = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spGender);
        EditText estaturaId = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.campoEstatura);


        if(nombreId.length()==0){
            nombre = null;
        }else{
            nombre = nombreId.getText().toString();
        }

        apellido = apellidoId.getText().toString();


        String valor = edadId.getText().toString();
        if(edadId.length()>0){
            edad = Integer.valueOf(valor);
        }

        sexo = sexoId.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String valor2 = estaturaId.getText().toString();
        if(estaturaId.length()>0){
            estatura = Integer.valueOf(valor2);
        }




              manager.insertar(nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,estatura);




}
```

Comment: Deberías depurar la aplicación para ver exactamente en que punto te está fallando. Pero a primera vista, no veo en tu código en que momento inicializas `manager`

Comment: Opino como @Pikoh, no veo que inicialices el manager, de todas maneras si haces que el método insertar sea estático (static) con hacer DataBase.insertar(...) valdría. Si con esto no lo arreglas revisa el método insertar no venga de ahí el problema. Apunte: Si sólo vas a utilizar el objeto DataBase para esa llamada no lo hagas global a la clase, hazlo local al método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas declarando una variable de tipo "DatabaseManager" :

```
private DataBase manager;
```

Pero no esta siendo inicializada en ningun lugar, por lo tanto, al llamar el método insertar de la clase DatabaseManager, lo estas realizando en una instancia con valor null.

```
manager.insertar(nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,estatura);
```

Inicializa la clase antes de llamar el método,

Por ejemplo de esta forma:

```
manager = new DataBase(getActivity ());
manager.insertar(nombre,apellido,edad,sexo,estatura);
```

Comment: Gracias, Olvidé ese pequeño detalle, Gracias!